# Fastest way to concatenate multiple strings 

Tags: java, java-me, stringbuilder, midp, string-concatenation

I'm working on a function that requires to concatenate multiple strings. Something like 200 - 500 strings.

I'm currently using StringBuffer. I wanted to know if this is the fastest way to concatenate multiple strings. I need this method to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: What exactly are you concatenating?

Comment: Does the concatenation operation need to be thread-safe? Becasue if not, you should probably be using StringBuilder .

Comment: StringBuilder is not available for Java 1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StringBuffer` with proper capacity `new StringBuffer(length)` is fastest way to concatenate strings in J2ME.

But before doing optimizations I would suggest you to profile application and find real place that require it.

If the string concatenation is issue. I would think a little bit different. I hardly believe that you're going to display this data to user. Most probably you're going to send it over the network. I would modify network protocol between my server and client (if you have this opportunity) to some raw format protocol and would write strings to `OtputStream` one by one without concatenation them to XML, JSON, etc

Answer (score 0):

in ASP.NET,
Concatenation is the process of appending one string to the end of another string. You concatenate strings by using the + operator. For string literals and string constants, concatenation occurs at compile time; no run-time concatenation occurs. For string variables, concatenation occurs only at run time.